# pyplot xticklabel (date/time) sometimes off by a minute

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a program that uses matplotlib.pyplot to produce a couple of graphs. On the x-axis I want to label the major ticks with a 4-hour time interval (so: 00:00, 04:00, 08:00 etc.)
When I plot the graph, the first few labels are okay but the rest isn't.

The code that I'm using (not showing the `ax3` being set-up and loading of the data as this is IMHO off-topic):

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use("Agg")                              # activate Anti-Grain Geometry library

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as nmp

:
:

hours     = mpl.dates.HourLocator()
fourhours = 4. / 24.
# [DAY]
major_ticks = nmp.arange(nmp.ceil(DY[1, 0]/fourhours)*fourhours, DY[-1, 0], fourhours)
ax3.set_xlabel('past day')
ax3.grid(True)
ax3.set_ylim([Ymin, Ymax])
ax3.set_xlim([DY[1, 0], DY[-1, 0]])
#
t = nmp.array(DY[:, 0])       # date/time
ax3.set_xticklabels(t, size='small')
ax3.set_yticklabels([])
ax3.set_xticks(major_ticks)
ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%R'))
ax3.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)
ax3.xaxis.set_minor_locator(hours)
ax3.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.2)
#
s = nmp.array(DY[:, 2])       # averages
slo = nmp.array(DY[:, 1])     # minima
shi = nmp.array(DY[:, 3])     # maxima
line, = ax3.plot(t, s, marker='.', linestyle='', color='red', lw=2)
ax3.fill_between(t, slo, shi, interpolate=True, color='red', alpha=0.2)
```

`DY[1,0]` contains the value `736364.444444`
`DY[-1,0]` is `736365.458333`
and `major_ticks` then becomes:
`[ 736364.5         736364.66666667  736364.83333333  736365.     736365.16666667  736365.33333333]`

This all looks fine to me but the resulting graph doesn't:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this are welcome.

@j-p-petersen proposed to use `linspace`:
I replaced the line that calculates `major_ticks = ...` with this code:

```
intervals = int((DY[-1, 0] - DY[1, 0]) / fourhours) + 1
major_ticks = np.linspace(np.ceil(DY[1, 0]/fourhours)*fourhours, np.floor(DY[-1, 0]/fourhours)*fourhours, intervals)
```

This reduced the problem but still some ticks show as one minute before the hour i.s.o. on the hour.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to a rounding error in the floating point arithmetic in here:

```
fourhours = 4. / 24.
```

Instead of using `arange` you could use `linspace`, this way it will not undershoot the target.

Alternatively you could do the calculation using `timedelta` and `deltatime`, and then afterwards convert it the Matplotlib's number dates with `matplotlib.dates.date2num`.

Comment: `linspace` performs a bit better. Not perfect alas.